# Android back-button-overriding etiquette / guidelines

Tags: android, back, convention

I have an app in which the user logs in from a main activity, and then can browse through a heirarchy of entities using listviews. So, the Activity stack would look something like this:

A -> B -> B -> B -> ...

where the number of B's is proportional to how deep you are in the tree of entities.
Frequently, I find myself pressing backbackbackbackback to get to the root (the first 'B'), but one too many presses and I log myself out, or even leave the app. I'm considering overriding the back button so that, when pressed from the root B, it will pop up a dialog essentially saying "Log out? (Y/N)", thus blocking a string of back-presses from completely exiting the app.

I've noticed a sort of sensitivity regarding overriding the back button, though, and - while it makes sense to me - I want to know if this is considered a good use of the back button.

So:
**Would this be considered an appropriate/conventional override of the back button?**
Is there a better/more conventional way to accomplish this without overriding?

Also, so this question might be more generally useful in the future, **are there any guidelines for what is acceptable/unacceptable when overriding the back button?**

Comment: This is no guideline, but in an application called Handcent SMS (I'll assume you've heard of this) there's an option where the back button will take you to the main page everytime you press it. This idea won't work in many applications though.

I'd say just implement something and then see how users react in testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find this use acceptable; I've seen a number of apps that ask for a confirm before exit - if the user wants to exit an app, they usually will press the Home button and let Android handle the finish() if and when it's needed.

I know I've accidentally exited an app by pressing back too many times :(

Dotmister's comment about Handcent is spot on - the back button should feel natural to the user; your use seems to adhere to this, in that a user will cycle back through activities as expected for the most part. As he said though, give it a try and test it.

Coincidentally, I have a similar flow in my app, but I've included a button for the root activity.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not normal to overide the back button because the user ecxpects the back button to function as a... ?? back button.

On the other side if it is really that annoying using the back button in the normal way, than a compremise? will always be better. But make sure the user still has the idea he 'controls' the device according his rules, do not make him look for yours. (dutch way of making a point, sorry).

The only way to find out is getting some people to try your application and see if it's annoying or not.